# Imap4Client SearchParse() doesn't work with special characters

Tags: c#, email, search, character-encoding, imap

I am using Imap4Client class and `SearchParse()` method to search email by subject. But this method doesn't work when email subject has some special characters like single quote `‘`.

```
Mailbox mails = Client.SelectMailbox("inbox");
MessageCollection messages = mails.SearchParse(EmailSubject);
```

Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: anybody have any answer ??

Comment: No idea what imap4client is. Is it poor enough that it doesn't quote/escape characters? If so you'll also have problems searching for ø and €, and much else. Try looking at its documentation or raising an issue for the library. Or switch to mailkit, which seems excellent.

Comment: @arnt the lib name is activeup.net.mail